# Convert a string to a custom JSX element and render it

Tags: reactjs

I am persistently storing parts of my data as JSX string representations of custom React components which I now want to retrieve from the database and render to the DOM.

I have tried https://github.com/milesj/interweave using `<Markup content={myJSX} />`

I have tried   `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:`
 ${myJSX} 
`}} />`

I have tried:

```
const teaserBoardHtml = `<div>test<br/> ${teaser_board} <br/> test</div>`
return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: teaserBoardHtml }}></div>
);
```

teaser_board is a string containing a custom react component

```
<MakeBoard {...someProps} />
```

It renders any HTML I put in the string, but not my custom react component - it renders nothing.

for example,     `const teaserBoardHtml = '<div>test <br/>' + teaser_board + ' test</div>'` will render test test, but nothing in the middle

None of these worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, you have to write html not JSX.

```
const myHtml = '<div class="toto"> <p> whatever </p> </div>';
```

then in your render

```
render() {
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: myHtml }} />
}
```

Comment: edited question to reflect the things I have tried and what is going wrong.